# Side load apps on android wear watch through iOS app

Tags: adb, bluetooth, ios, android-wear

I am wondering if it's possible to side load apps on an android wear watch through Bluetooth debugging from the android wear app on iOS.

I have a Moto 360 2nd Gen and I recently bought an iPhone. I feel quite limited in terms of watch faces and apps In general.

Unfortunately, my watch doesn't have any ports as it charges wirelessly and the only way to sideload apps is by doing it through Bluetooth. Now seeming as there is a debug function on the android wear app for iOS (haven't seen this function yet, so correct me if there isn't) I can conclude that if i download the adb drivers for my watch, the computer can communicate with the watch, using the iPhone as a tunnel.

My main question is whether this is possible. I may have misunderstood something, in case of that please correct me and direct me towards the right way.

Thanks for your time, any help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Sid.